# special symbol in href value of anchor tag

Tags: html

What is the role of # and ! in href value?

```
<a href="#!${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dic/users/home.ct" rel="home">
```

Comment: needs more info, looks like you're using some sort of templating engine.  Can you link to where you saw this code?

Comment: @nak yeah, almost looks like a bug, that it was intended to get translated by the server into something.

Answer (score 1):

`#` points to an anchor (`<a name="xx">` or `<element id="xx">`)

The bang is probably for [ajax-crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) compatibility. The combined `#!` is used to signal Googlebot that your site supports the scheme.

This link scheme should only be used from javascript, not printed to the HTML. In this case the page doesn't actually have an anchor called `!contextPath`, but there should be a page at `/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dic/users/home.ct`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]It's become the standard that Google has established to ensure consistency and make ajax urls crawlable.

See http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

I believe they are using `history.pushState`. You can do `history.back()` in the console and it'll lead you back to the page.

By the way, "!" is used to eliminate the case with an empty hash. "http://url#" will make a browser to slide to the top.

Comment: When you need link-like visuals but not a link (cases where you'd use `href='#'` or `javascript:void(0)`), you should add it via CSS and `tabindex=0`, no need for an unused anchor.